# How to properly encode email message in python script running on Synology NAS

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I got the following script, to send automatic emails every day, which is working very fine on any PC.

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content("""Σύμφωνα με όσα ..""") #email body
msg["Subject"] = "Email Subject"
msg["From"] = "sender@hotmail.com"
msg["To"] = "receiver@hotmail.com"

context=ssl.create_default_context()

with smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp-mail.outlook.com', port=587) as smtp:
    smtp.starttls(context=context)
    smtp.login(msg["From"], "email_password")
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

I need to setup that script to run on Synology NAS. I am able to run the script, and the email is sended successfully. The problem is that, the body of the email is written on Greek language. If the script is running on Any of my PCs, the body is readable and the email is excelent. When sending from the Synology, the body part is broken, and i see only : ����

I spend some time looking for solutions, and found that i can add the following, before the code, to declare the script encoding:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8-sig -*-
```

Also, i found [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174485/python3-unicodeencodeerror-when-run-via-synology-task-scheduler), but those solutions isn't working for my case.
I am also using the task scheduler, so i can try any other fixes like those in the above code.
Any ideas what i can do to fix that issue ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the raw message, including headers, as received in the client?

Answer (score 0):

After spending some more time, i found the following code, which is also working nicely on the nas:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib, ssl

port = 587  # For starttls
smtp_server = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"
sender_email = "sender@hotmail.com"
receiver_email = "receiver@hotmail.com"
password = "sender_password"
message = str.encode("""Subject: EMAIL SUBJECT

EMAIL BODY TEXT""")

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

'I've also tried to use `str.encode()` on the old script, but i am getting decoding errors, so i decided to use the new script.